# Count the number of elements in array in Python whatever dimension it is

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to count easily the number of elements in a NumPy array, but I don't know a priori their dimensions. Is there a generic function that counts the number of elements in a `numpy` array whatever its dimension is?

Comment: [shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)

Comment: [numpy.ndarray.size](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) would help you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[numpy.ndarray.size](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) returns a number of elements in the array

```
>>> x = np.zeros((3, 5, 2), dtype=np.complex128)
>>> x.size
30
```